# Convexity of a Log Likelihood Function

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis, normal-distribution, positive-semidefinite, log-likelihood

#### Goal

I would like to proof than the Negative Log Likelihood Function of Sample drawn from a Normal Distribution is convex.

Below a Figure showing an example of such function:

[image]

Motivation of this question is detailed at the end of the post.

#### Sketching the demonstration

What I did so far...

First I have written the likelihood function for a single observation:

$$\mathcal{L} (\mu, \sigma \mid x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$

For convenience I take the Negative Logarithm of the Likelihood function, I think it does not change the extremum because Logarithm is a monotonic function:

$$f(\mu, \sigma \mid x) = -\ln \mathcal{L} (\mu, \sigma \mid x) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi) + \ln(\sigma) +\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$

Then I can assess the Jacobian (check: [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff((1%2F2)*log(2*pi)%20%2B%20log(s)%20%2B%20(x-m)%5E2%2F(2*s%5E2),m)) and [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff((1%2F2)*log(2*pi)%20%2B%20log(s)%20%2B%20(x-m)%5E2%2F(2*s%5E2),s))):

$$
\mathbf{J}_f = \left[
\begin{matrix}
     -\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}\\
     -\frac{(x-\mu)^2 - \sigma^2}{\sigma^3}
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

And the Hessian (check [3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff(diff((1%2F2)*log(2*pi)%20%2B%20log(s)%20%2B%20(x-m)%5E2%2F(2*s%5E2),m),m)), [4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff(diff((1%2F2)*log(2*pi)%20%2B%20log(s)%20%2B%20(x-m)%5E2%2F(2*s%5E2),m),s)) and [5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff(diff((1%2F2)*log(2*pi)%20%2B%20log(s)%20%2B%20(x-m)%5E2%2F(2*s%5E2),s),s))):

$$
\mathbf{H} = \left[
\begin{matrix}
     \frac{1}{\sigma^2} & \frac{2(x - \mu)}{\sigma^3} \\
     \frac{2(x - \mu)}{\sigma^3} & \frac{3(x - \mu)^2 - \sigma^2}{\sigma^4} 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Of the Negative Log Likelihood function.

Now, I compute the Hessian of the Negative Log Likelihood function for $N$ observations:

$$
\mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\mathbf{H} = \left[
\begin{matrix}
     \frac{1}{\sigma^2} &  \frac{2(\bar{x} - \mu)}{\sigma^3} \\
     \frac{2(\bar{x} - \mu)}{\sigma^3} & \frac{\frac{3}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}(x-\mu)^2 - \sigma^2}{\sigma^4} 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

If everything is right at this point:

- Proving the function is convex is equivalent to prove than the Hessian is semi-positive definite;

Additionally I know that:

- A semi-positive definite Matrix must have all its eigenvalues non-negative;
- Because the Hessian Matrix is symmetric, all eigenvalues are real;

So if I prove than all eigenvalues are positive real numbers, then I can claim the function is convex. We can also check, as @LinAlg suggested, that both determinant and trace of Matrix $\mathbf{A}$ are positive:

$$
\begin{align}
\det(\mathbf{A}) \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow & \frac{3}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}(x-\mu)^2 - \sigma^2 - 4(\bar{x} - \mu)^2  \geq 0 \\
\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{A}) \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow & \frac{3}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}(x-\mu)^2 \geq 0
\end{align}
$$

It is obvious that $\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{A}) \geq 0$.

#### Inequality

The inequality $\det(\mathbf{A}) \geq 0$ is not obvious at the first glance, it requires a bit of algebra. Expanding all squares, applying sum, simplifying and grouping gives:

$$
3\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}x^2 - \bar{x}^2\right] -(\bar{x}-\mu)^2 -\sigma^2 \geq 0
$$

Now I can rewrite it using Standard Deviation Estimation:

$$
3\left[\frac{N-1}{N}s^2_x - \sigma^2\right] + 2\sigma^2 \geq (\bar{x}-\mu)^2
$$

For $N$ sufficiently large it tends to:

$$
3\left(s^2_x - \sigma^2\right) + 2\sigma^2 \geq (\bar{x}-\mu)^2
$$

Or:

$$
\left|\bar{x}-\mu\right| \leq \sqrt{3s^2_x - \sigma^2}
$$

Provided the radicand is non -negative. This last inequality provides a bound for Mean Asbolute Error which must be lower than approximately $\sqrt{2}\sigma$. Finally, if the estimators converge to expected values it reduces to:

$$
\sigma \geq 0
$$

Which is trivially true by definition.

My interpretation of this inequality is:

If we have sufficiently large statistics, drawn from a Normal Distribution, and the Mean and Variance Estimation are close enough to their expected value then the Negative Likelihood Function should be convex. If expected values $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are known, it is possible to assess the convexity.

#### Questions

- Are my reasoning and the interpretation of the result correct?
- Can we formally prove that $\det(\mathbf{A}) \geq 0$?

#### Motivation

This question arose from a numerical example I develop. I am sampling from a Normal Distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu=2, \sigma=3)$ with $N=1000$ and I would like to emphasize all steps of a Maximum Likelihood Estimation. Then when I visualized the function to minimize I wondered: Can we say that this function is convex? Which made me write this post on MSE.

[image]
 [image]
 [image]
 [image]

Comment: Your simplification of $A$ is not correct, since you 'abuse' Bias and $\sigma$. The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues and the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, so it suffices to check if the trace and determinant are positive.

Comment: @LinAlg, Thank you for the comment could you be more explicit, what do you mean by abusing the bias and sigma?

Comment: sigma and bias do not depend on data but are fixed numbers based on the probility distrubtion

Comment: @LinAlg I have updated my post to take your remarks into account. Would you mind review it? I have some difficulty to show that $\det(\mathbf{A})\geq 0$. Thank you.

Comment: I have checked your steps and they are correct. For fixed $x$ you get an ellipsoid on which the function is convex.